# qbasic what is the difference between open "file.dat" for input as #1 or input as #2

Tags: qbasic

Now i am on grade 10 and i am learning about open"file.dat" for input/output as #n
once have a look at my program

```
cls

open "samrat.dat" for output as #1

input "enter your name";n$

write #1,n$

close #1

end
```

so with this program i save my name to the file
now i use output as #n to print this number. have a look at my next program

```
cls

open "samrat.dat" for input as #1

input #1,n$

print n$

close #1

end
```

so this program will print my or user name. but one thing is confusing me. if i will use open "samrat.dat" for input as #5 and change the #1 into #5 in all the places the output is same. I dont quite understand how it works. if #1 is same as #1000 what is the need of other number. 
please tell me

Comment: Consider a case where you need to have multiple files open for writing at the same time.

Comment: You can use any file number up to 32767.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, your program will work as long as you use the same filenumber on all the places. The filenumber is just a token to tell the different files appart in your program.

It is possible for a program to access more than one file at the same time.
For example you could read from one file, process the input, and then write it to another file.

```
OPEN infile$ FOR INPUT AS #1
OPEN outfile$ FOR OUTPUT AS #2
INPUT #1, A$
A$ = UCASE$(A$)
PRINT #2, A$
'etc.
```